# element is not attached to the page document, but I'm sure it is?

Tags: javascript, python, selenium, visual-studio-code, webdriver

EDIT5 : Here's the file : https://drive.google.com/file/d/1wlEtvYntnJRDA-OZ3IQPaLmECL6YyHl4/view?usp=sharing You can compile and check for yourself.

I'm using Python + Selenium with VSCode and Vscode throws me this error whenever my code restarts.

I've got code set in a loop to grab an element by class and then do operations on that element, specifically this :

```
self.actions.context_click(self.driver.execute_script("elm = document.getElementsByClassName('member-3-YXUe')[arguments[0]]; return elm", cnt)).perform()
```

This code is set in a loop, but it only works properly the first time. The second time it always throws the above error. I couldn't for the life of me figure out why it does that. Put in mind that the value of "elm" as is obvious is refreshed in each iteration, and I'm pretty sure the element I'm targeting is still there and has the same properties I'm referencing it by. I even tried to make a long sleep delay in order to make sure quick loading between page refreshs is not a problem. Nothing worked.

It always works the first time, and it always fails the second time with the same error. What could be causing this?

EDIT: I also tried using Python to get the element and I also tried separating the element-finding from the perform()

EDIT2 : I'm working with Discord. A Discord server's user element from the server user list to be specific.

EDIT3: Here's my loop code. Perhaps it's a misreferenced error or something.

```
while (users <= 5):

    users += 1
    #cnt += 1

    sleep(2)

    #scroll down user list
    print("\n------------------------------Scroll down list------------------------------")
    
    #elm.click()
    self.driver.execute_script("\
        elm = document.getElementsByClassName('membersWrap-2h-GB4')[0];\
        elm.scrollTo(0, elm.scrollHeight + 1000);\
        //elm.innerHTML = '';\
        ")

    print("\n------------------------------get user user------------------------------")
    sleep(1)

    #get user 
    user = self.driver.execute_script("elm = document.getElementsByClassName('member-3-YXUe')[arguments[0]]; return elm", cnt)

    print("\n------------------------------click on a user------------------------------")
    sleep(2)

    #right click user and message
    print("\n0--------------------")

    self.actions.context_click(self.driver.execute_script("elm = document.getElementsByClassName('member-3-YXUe')[arguments[0]]; return elm", cnt)).perform()

    print("\n1--------------------")
    elm = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[contains(@id, 'user-context-message-user')]")

    print("\n2--------------------")
    elm.click()

    print("\n------------------------------Add Friend------------------------------")
    #sleep(2)
    #elm = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//button[contains(@class, "button-38aScr")]')
    #elm.click()
    
    print("\n------------------------------type message------------------------------")
    sleep(2)

    elm = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[contains(@data-slate-object, "block")]')
    elm.send_keys("Hoi")
    elm.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)

    sleep(2)
    print("\n------------------------------Go back to server------------------------------")
    elm = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[contains(@data-list-item-id, "guildsnav___756234166877683762")]')

    elm.click()
    cnt += 1
    self.driver.get("https://discord.com/channels/756234166877683762/756235051540414584")
    sleep(5)

self.driver.quit()
```

EDIT4 : More clarification -- The first time the code is run I'm able to log in into discord, go to the specific server, get the first user in the server, DM them, and then go back to the server. At this point the bot gives the error, when I try t grab the same user or the next user in the indexed list. I've also tried grabbing users by attributes rather than classes. I'm not sure this is a Discord protection thingie, it really smells of a bad loop or Python/VSCode error.

EDIT6: I tried looping the entire script, closing and re-opening the webdriver and the chrome window. Somehow this doesn't turn up with the error, while trying twice in the same window would lead to the second try failing as mentioned before. Still don't know why this happens. Maybe it has something to do with persistent values of variables or the local browser storage? For when the session is terminated and restarted after every iteration nothing wrong happens.

Comment: Can you provide a link to the page you are working with?

Comment: @Eliyahu I'm working with Discord. A Discord server's user element from the user list to be specific.

Comment: Could you check whether `'member-3-YXUe` is the same after the refresh, this looks like a generated `className` in order to avoid/block such things like bots etc.. Also it could be the SPA problem.

Comment: I did that already. That's why I couldn't figure it out. Every user div element has that class name and even after refreshing the page it's still there. I was keeping an eye out for auto generated values and after testing I realized this was a persistent class. Suffice to say if it was generated then it shouldn't work every single time I run the bot from VSCode once and then gives that error.

Comment: And if they had a kind of protection against Bots I'm sure it won't allow the Bot to work properly the first time. Each time it's run. The first time the code is run I'm able to log in into discord, go to the specific server, get the first user in the server, DM them, and then go back to the server. At this point the bot gives the error.